# How to get duplicate values only once and other one multiple time from same table in php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have 2 tables.one is accounts and other is bookings.

[image: account table]

[image: booking table]

i want to get data from booking table as duplicate data should display only once but all the data for start field from the selected UId. in the following format.

**date** : 2014-12-20
**start :** 7:00,7:30,8:00,8:30,9:00,9:30
**players :** 0
**comments :** test booking

```
$comp_query1=mysql_query("select * from bookings where UId = '$contact_id'");
    while($booking=mysql_fetch_array($comp_query1))
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
<td><strong>comments : </strong></td>
<td><?php echo $booking['comments']; ?></td>
</tr>
     <tr>
<td><strong>Date : </strong></td>
<td><?php echo $booking['date']; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><strong>Players : </strong></td>
<td><?php echo $booking['Players']; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Start : </strong></td>
<td>    <?php echo $booking['start']; ?>


 </td>
</tr>
```

this is my query. Help me.
Thank u in advance.

Comment: You *could* use GROUP_CONCAT, but I'd just return an ordered array, and do it with a simple PHP loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create an array with your `key`, if you already have it just append the `data` to the value you already stored.

Something like (To translate into PHP) :

```
while () {
  if (!array_containskey($bookings, $booking[id])){
    $bookings[$booking[id]] = $booking;
  } else {
    bookings[$booking[id]][date] .= ",".$booking[date] ;// append
  }
}
```

Then you can loop on your new array with correct values.

Comment: Well i've no time to code it for you, but sure it works. Just put the algorithm on paper nothing fancy.

Answer (score 0):

```
select `date` , 
GROUP_CONCAT(
`start` order by `start` asc
) as `start`,

GROUP_CONCAT(
comments order by `start` asc
) as comments,
SUM(`Players`) as `Players`
from bookings 
where UId = '$contact_id'
group by `date`;
```

This should  result in

date : 2014-12-20 
start : 7:00,7:30,8:00,8:30,9:00,9:30 
players : 0 
comments : test booking, test booking ,....

Then you could simply loop through the different row for each date and display the results

Answer (score 0):

i got the simplest way to do that by using implode function

```
 <?php 
    $comp_query1=mysql_query("select * from bookings where UId = '$contact_id'");
    $book = array();
    while($booking=mysql_fetch_array($comp_query1))
    {
        $comments = $booking['comments'];
        $date = $booking['date'];
        $players = $booking['Players'];
        $book[] = $booking['start'];
        $comma_separated = implode(' | ', $book);
    }
    ?>
    <tr>
<td><strong>comments : </strong></td>
<td><?php echo $comments; ?></td>
</tr>
     <tr>
<td><strong>Date : </strong></td>
<td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><strong>Players : </strong></td>
<td><?php echo $players; ?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><strong>Start : </strong></td>
<td>    <?php echo $comma_separated; ?>


 </td>
</tr>
```